# I need help setting up a .gitlab-ci.yml file for C++

Tags: c++, git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

The GitLab documentation is lacking and not very clear. How do I setup this file to automatically build my C++ project (it will tell you if it passes or fails) and how do I configure to have separate builds for Windows/Mac/Linux. If you need me to share my repo with you just ask.

Comment: Just show us the .gitlab-ci.yml file .

Comment: @Kiloreux I don't have one yet because I don't understand how to set one up for c++. I use gitlab.com and use their shared runners. I'm new to CI and I looked at the docs for the .gitlab-ci.yml file but couldn't figure out how to do one for c++, their example one was for ruby on rails (which I don't know).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before you automate anything run it manually. Write a shell script then put that in CI. Below is a simple template using the shell executor.

```
before_script:
   - export BUILD_VAR=if_needed

build_linux:
   stage: build
   script:
      - my_build_script.sh
```

If your steps are simple you can put them directly in the CI config:

```
build_linux:
   stage: build
   script:
      - ./configure
      - make
```

Get that working for your simplest case and then grow it from there.

Comment: ok, what should I put in my script do I have to build with cmake or something else? sorry I'm pretty new to the c++ community I'm used to unity and other easier languages but I love learning and c++ is awesome. Right now I just have a basic game so the commands shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: It is customary to have an out-of-tree build with CMake, so you may want to have a before script that sets up a build directory. You will need to create a cache and set up whatever variables you want set in your project, then build. `cmake {PATH_TO_CMakeLists.txt} --DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_FLAG_EXAMPLE:BOOL=ON` and build: `cmake --build .`. `cmake --build .` will work on all platforms, but will not be parallelized -- you may want to use a platform-specific build command like `make` or `MSBuild` with appropriate arguments to run in parallel.

Answer (score 6):

To build a C++ application, you will need a compiler. You can use an existing Docker image that has a compiler. I'm using the `gcc` image here.

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file. You don't have to use `CMake`, just put in whatever commands you need to build your application and make sure you've satisfied the build dependencies in the image.

```
# Use the official gcc image
image: gcc

before_script:
    # Install build dependencies
    - apt-get update && apt-get -y install cmake

myapp:
    # Build the application
    stage: build
    script:
        - mkdir build
        - cd build
        - cmake ..
        - make
```

That should be enough to get you started.