# Is it possible to not use _any_ Docker image in CI mode for GitLab?

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration

I've got a repository that has a series of documents (multimarkdown files, PDFs, GSN arguments, etc.) that need to use our internal (currently) proprietary tool to assemble those documents into a HTML-like document. The internal tool is quite complicated to use and isn't (yet) deployable.

What I tried doing was compiling the internal tool on the Ubuntu VM that I knew would be used for this job and then not tell GitLab (we're using self-hosted GitLab) to use any docker image when it tried to assemble the documents. Alas, when the CI job was run, I saw:

```
Pulling docker image alpine:latest ...
```

And then, of course, none of the stuff I installed on the VM itself was available.

1. Is there a way to have GitLab run the CI job without any Docker image?
2. If not (or if this alternative is just plain "better"), what is a good resource for reading how to install this complicated internal tool into a Docker image?

NB: The current methodology for "installing" the complicated internal tool, in addition to a lot of installing packages via apt-get, etc., (which I already have examples of how to do in Docker), is to clone the repository, and then run `npm install` and `rake install` in the cloned directory.

Comment: Are you using self-hosted GitLab?

Comment: @geektechstuff Yes, I should have mentioned that. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by your GitLab-runner configuration. When the runner uses the `docker` executor it will *always* use a docker image for the build. If you want to run a GitLab job without using docker, you will need to configure a GitLab runner with the "shell" executor on your VM.

---

However, using `image: ubuntu:focal` or similar is likely enough. You usually don't have to be concerned about the fact that an executor happens to run your job inside of a container. This is also beneficial, as it means your build environment is *reproducible* and that process will be defined in your job.

```
myjob:
  image: ubuntu:focal
  script:
    - apt update && apt install -y nodejs ruby # or whatever else
    # - npm install
    # - gem install
    # - rake install
    # etc...
    -
```

Or better yet, if you can produce a docker image with your core dependencies installed you can just use `image: my-special-image` in your GitLab job to use that image as your build environment.

Comment: I tried using `ubuntu:focal` but the executable I installed on the VM wasn't found. Note that the script portion of my job is something like: `- export PATH=path-to-exe:$PATH`, `- cd pkg-dir`, and `build-pkg`, where the latter would be my executable. Can you tell me more about the "shell" executor?

Comment: @BenHocking right -- you can only use executables on the host when using the shell executor. Otherwise you must install the software as part of your job when using the docker executor. Runners must be configured to use an executor. There are several available. The most common being docker, kubernetes, and [shell](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html). The shell executor is what you want if you want builds to be able to use software installed on the host where the runner is running.

Comment: I feel like I'm being dense, but GitLab's instructions don't tell me how to modify my .gitlab-ci.yml file to not use a Docker image. Rather they're telling me how to modify my (currently non-existant) config.toml file. Another answer seems to suggest that `shell` is run by default, but that's not the case for me (I'm getting `alpine:latest`). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814259/i-need-help-setting-up-a-gitlab-ci-yml-file-for-c

Comment: It seems that `config.toml` is per runner and not per project, so modifications to that would affect other jobs using the same runner. I'm guessing I would want to create a runner just for this project then and make it use that file.

Comment: Actually, in looking deeper, it seems that `config.toml` is not even per runner? We have just one `config.toml` file. I don't currently see any distinction between our Ubuntu VM, our Windows VMs, or our Mac VM.